# org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity

Tags: http, post, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using below code to do http post and upload a file and getting below mentioned error.

Am I missing something here?

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();   
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serverEndpointUrl + attachementsResource);
System.out.println(serverEndpointUrl + attachementsResource);
request.addHeader("Authorization", getBasicAuth(Authorization));
builder.addBinaryBody("file", fileContent,ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileName);
HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
request.setEntity(multipart);
response = client.execute(request);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
```

Please suggest

Comment: which version of http client are you using?